# Как в django ограничить доступ?

Tags: django, model, users

У меня есть приложение в котором все пользователи после регистрации могут публиковать статьи, как мне сделать так чтобы публиковать могли лишь те которые имеют права для этого(что то вроде обычных юзеров и модераторов/редакторов и как выдавать эти права. Ниже прикреплен код:

models.py/blogapp

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name=("Заголовок"), max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    header_image = models.ImageField(verbose_name=("Заглавное Изображение"), null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/" )
    body = RichTextField(verbose_name=("Тело Статьи"), blank=True, null=True)
    #body = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.CharField(verbose_name=("Категория"), max_length=200)
    snippet = models.CharField(verbose_name=("Фрагмент Статьи"), max_length=200)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='blog_post')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
    

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' | ' + str(self.author)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

views.py/members

```
class CreateProfilePageView(CreateView):
    model = Profile
    form_class = ProfilePageForm
    template_name = "registration/create_user_profile.html"
    #fields = '__all__'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

class EditProfilePageView(generic.UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'registration/edit_profile_page.html'
    fields = ['bio', 'profile_pic', 'website_url', 'instagram_url', 'twitter_url', 'status',  'age']

    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

class ShowProfilePageView(DetailView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'registration/user_profile.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #users = Profile.objects.all()
        context = super(ShowProfilePageView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

        page_user = get_object_or_404(Profile, id=self.kwargs['pk'])

        context["page_user"] = page_user
        return context

class PasswordsChangeView(PasswordChangeView):
    form_class = PasswordChangingForm
    #form_class = PasswordChangeForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('password_success')
    #success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

def password_success(request):
    return render(request, 'registration/password_success.html', {})

class UserRegisterView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = SignUpForm
    template_name = 'registration/registr.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')


class UserEditView(generic.UpdateView):
    form_class = EditProfileForm
    template_name = 'registration/edit_profile.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

views.py/blogapp

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Post
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(draft=False)
    cats = Category.objects.all()
    template_name = 'home.html'
    ordering = ['-post_date']
    paginate_by = 6

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cat_menu = Category.objects.all()
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["cat_menu"] = cat_menu
        return context

def CategoryListView(request):
    cat_menu = Category.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'category_list.html', {'cat_menu':cat_menu})


def CategoryView(request, cats):
    category_posts = Post.objects.filter(category = cats). order_by('-post_date')
    return render(request, 'categories.html', {'cats':cats.title(), 'category_posts':category_posts})


class ArticleDetailView(HitCountDetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'
    count_hit = True


    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cat_menu = Category.objects.all()
        context = super(ArticleDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

        stuff = get_object_or_404(Post, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        total_likes = stuff.total_likes()

        context["cat_menu"] = cat_menu
        context["total_likes"] = total_likes
        return context



class AddPostView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name= 'add_post.html'
    #fields = '__all__'

class AddCommentView(CreateView):
    model = Comment
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name= 'add_comment.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('article_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk']})

class AddCategoryView(CreateView):
    model = Category
    template_name= 'add_category.html'
    fields = '__all__'


class UpdatePostView(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'update_post.html'
    form_class = EditForm
    #fields = ['title', 'body']

class DeletePostView(DeleteView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'delete_post.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

Если нужен еще какой либо код прикреплю его, спасибо.

Comment: Можно юзеров поделить на группы и каждой группе давать определенные права доступа.

Comment: Спасибо опробую)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все просто.

Права - [тут](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization)

А как использовать во View - [тут](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#the-permissionrequiredmixin-mixin)

Comment: окей по читаю спасибо)